# Fill an area with color in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter to develop an app and I have a row in a card with three items, I am try to fill the area for the last item with a color but there seems to be padding around the area that I just do not how to get rid of.

Here is the situation at the moment:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
return new Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0,horizontal: 16.0),
      child: new InkWell(
        child: new Card(
          child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new ListTile(
                  leading: new Image.asset("images/${aps.photo}",fit: BoxFit.contain,),
                  title: new Text(aps.university),),

              ),
              new Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  color: Colors.blue,child: new Text("${aps.aps}",style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

All I want to achieve is to fill the entire area with score with the blue color. The color must stretch to the top and bottom.

Comment: Why do you set a padding to begin with, if you don't want it ?

Comment: The padding I set here `padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0)` was to try to expand the size of the container. I am referring to padding around the container that houses the points

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to set on your `Row` `crossAxisAlignment` to `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`.
This will force all it's children to expand vertically. 
But then you have to add an height constraint or else the row will expand on the vertical axis.

The easiest solution in your case is to wrap your `Row` into a `SizedBox` with a fixed height and unconstrained width. Where the height would be equal to `ListTile` height, as it's the biggest element of your list. So 56.0, considering you have a one line title and without `dense` property.

Then you may want to align your `Text` inside the colored container. As it's top aligned instead of vertical centered.
Which can be achieved with the `alignment` property on `Container` set to `Alignment.center` or `Alignment.centerLeft/Right` depending on your need.

```
new Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 16.0),
  child: new InkWell(
    child: new Card(
      child: new SizedBox(
        height: 56.0,
        child: new Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new ListTile(
                title: new Text('foo'),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                child: new Text(
                  "foo",
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! worked like a charm! Much appreciated

Comment: @RémiRousselet I'm trying to do almost the same but to color the bottom of a Card. Each time, The SizeedBox overflows the bottom of the card, making the round corners of the card disappear

Comment: @rémi-rousselet Is there any way to achieve it without using height constraints?