# Color bottom of Card in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm building a layout with a GridView and Cards. I want to put a color to the bottom of each card. I found this question [Fill an area with color in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540867/fill-an-area-with-color-in-flutter) and tried to do the same trick for bottom, but each time The SizedBox Overflows the round card corners. Any idea of how to fix this?

The sample code below shows the issue. I try to color the bottom part of the card, and when I do this, the corners of the card are lost, like overflow from the Container.

[image]
[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        elevation: 10,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 100,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("line1"),
              Text(
                "line2",
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                /*color: Colors.orange,*/ child: Text("Bottom"),
              )), 
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(),
      )
    ],
  ),      
);
```

}

Comment: Can you provide your current `Card` code and an image example for what you wish for them to look like?

Comment: Might have found the solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866481/flutter-how-to-create-card-with-background-image

And then a restart of the simulator :(

Answer (score 4):

Try using `BoxDecoration` in your `Container` and use the same radius as your `Card` (4.0)

```
            Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.orange,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(4.0))),
                          child: Text("Bottom"),
                        ),
                      ),
```