# BoxConstraints forces an infinite width - how to avoid setting a hard width or height?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Plenty of questions already on box contraints forcing an infinite width or height.

For example, this solution recommends setting a hard height
[Fill an area with color in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49540867/fill-an-area-with-color-in-flutter)

Could we achieve the same without setting hard limits, so the box is fitted to the contents?

What would be the solution, if we remove the height?

```
new Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 16.0),
  child: new InkWell(
    child: new Card(
      child: new SizedBox(
        height: 56.0,
        child: new Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new ListTile(
                title: new Text('foo'),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                child: new Text(
                  "foo",
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: You may want IntrinsicHeight instead of the SizedBox

Comment: Yes, that worked. Fantastic! Plesae post as answer, so I can accept.